Edge: You don't have the user rights to view this page. What user rights?
I'm trying to track a Fedex package and get this 403 error.

The closest result I could find:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/access-denied-you-dont-have-permission-to-access/2670da60-ce07-45a4-a2f1-9797cb3b9ac5
Fired up Thunderbird, works no problem.
The only errors I could find even recently were:

Log Name:      OAlerts Source:        Microsoft Office 16 Alerts Date:
10/26/2024 3:54:13 PM Event ID:      300 Task Category: None Level:
Error Keywords:      Classic User:          DESKTOP-GG6AA6L\cdi
Computer:      DESKTOP-GG6AA6L Description: Failed to parse element:
VersionOverrides Id=bc13b9d0-5ba2-446a-956b-c583bdc94d5e,
DisplayName=Suggested Meetings, Provider=Microsoft, StoreType=Unknown,
StoreId=(null) P1: Apps for Office P2: 16.0.18025.20030 P3: 0x8004323E
P4: New Document

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft Office 16 Alerts" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">300</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-10-26T20:54:13.0282248Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8866</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>OAlerts</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-GG6AA6L</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1321591578-1025125094-2043397002-1011" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Failed to parse element: VersionOverrides
</Data>
    <Data>Id=bc13b9d0-5ba2-446a-956b-c583bdc94d5e, DisplayName=Suggested Meetings, Provider=Microsoft, StoreType=Unknown, StoreId=(null)
</Data>
    <Data>Apps for Office
</Data>
    <Data>16.0.18025.20030
</Data>
    <Data>0x8004323E
</Data>
    <Data>New Document
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

What permissions do they mean?  I was able to reach Fedex earlier today.  And, of course, Firefox reaches it fine.
new variant:
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.fedex.com/en-ca/home.html" on this server.
Reference #18.7018d017.1730091551.6e5bab74

https://errors.edgesuite.net/18.7018d017.1730091551.6e5bab74

which leads to this most unlikely page content:
Uh oh! Something went wrong with the previous request.
If you navigated here, it's because the previous request experienced an error. If you are the site owner, you can use the Translate Error String tool to investigate this further. This is located on the control center under:

Hamburger menu > SUPPORT > Edge Diagnostics.


That's just a generic 403 page they're using for errors, with wording that indeed sounds unusual.
If it works for you in another browser, you could attempt to:

refresh and clear cache on that page with Ctrl + F5
click the lock icon next to the URL in address bar and remove all cookies for the domain
launch the browser in incognito mode and try there - if it works, some extension could be conflicting with site's code
make sure you don't use any VPN or anything alike accidentally, as it could be related to blocked IPs

If nothing works, it might be an unsolvable by you and perhaps temporary problem on the website's side.
